# Ubuntu Touch: aa-exec and xmir app

Tags: ubuntu-touch, apparmor

I created a GTK application, and I can successfully run it on Ubuntu Phone via a `.desktop` launcher like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=lazSnake Dev
Comment=Simple snake game written in Lazarus by Kris Jacewicz
X-Ubuntu-Touch=true
X-Ubuntu-XMir-Enable=true
Exec=./lazsnake
Icon=./lazsnake.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

I emphasize that it works, no problem. Then, I build a click package of my app, it works (meaning it builds), and finally I install the app from the click package I built. Now, because of how click works, the new launcher does no longer call the executable directly, instead it runs it under AppArmor, notice the difference in the "Exec" entry of the new Desktop launcher:

```
Exec=aa-exec-click -p ubuntu-lazsnake-app.kriscode_ubuntu-lazsnake-app_0.9 -- ./lazsnake
```

Now, starting the app with this new launcher will fail. However, calling it with a custom launcher which does not use "`aa-exec-click`" will work.

My question is: what does `AppArmor`/`aa-exec-click` has to do with xmir that I can't run my app with it? Is there some special setting I need to add in `manifest.json` or other file before building the click package?

Comment: Apparently once click package is installed the name is somehow registered. In order for me to make the launcher from click work again, I have to also (in addition to Exec filed) change the Name field to something new, otherwise it still won't start.

Comment: If you found an acceptable solution you can answer your own question.